# How do I resolve a spurious "No suitable Java version found" message?

Tags: java, launchpad, eclipse

Usually, when I a terminal session on an IBM Midrange box, I use a Java-based TN5250 emulator I designed and helped write (but which, alas, is not available to the public except as part of another application).

But occasionally, I need to use the open source TN5250J instead.

I'm in the final stages of migrating from Catalina on a 2017 iMac to Ventura on an M2 Mini. And I noticed two problems with TN5250J:

First, it doesn't show up in Launchpad.

And second, if I find the app, and try to launch it, I get

> ERROR launching 'Tn5250j'
>
> No suitable Java version found on your system! This program requires
> Java 1.6+ Make sure you install the required Java version.

I tried the supposed solution (counterintuitive as it is) at https://stackoverflow.com/q/52782711 but "no joy."

Any other ideas of how to fix this? TN5250J shouldn't be fussy about any remotely current JVM.

This gets worse: Eclipse also fails to launch. It comes back with a different message (and I think it's from some part ofEclipse itself):

```
Alert
Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine
```

To answer the question from "greg-449," a `/usr/libexec/java_home --verbose` returns

```
    1.8.0_121 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_09 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And I will note that if anything runs under the Java 7 JVM, text rendering is seriously screwed up.

I'm wondering if I simply need to reinstall Java, given that these are x86 JVMs, running on M2 hardware.

Comment: Ventura doesn't ship a JVM, so you will need to install one.

Comment: The JVMs from my Catalina box must have transferred over; other Java programs (that launch from AppleScript launchers) work just fine.

Comment: Try running `/usr/libexec/java_home --verbose` to list all the Java installations the system knows about

Comment: Results (and additional symptoms and speculation) added to the question.  Thanks.

Comment: There is a similar problem on the github issues page for TN5250J - https://github.com/tn5250j/tn5250j/issues/82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that none of the suggestions I tried actually accomplished anything (and one broke other Java programs), and that either (1) digging into the existing app and double-clicking the JAR, or (2) launching it with an Applescript app, seems to work just fine, I see no reason to bother with attempting to "repackage" something I rarely use (remember, I said I use a completely different TN5250 client most of the time, one I *designed* and had a hand in writing), and had no hand in writing.

FWIW, I offer here the source for a simple AppleScript launcher, based on one that I wrote many years ago to launch a JAR under a specific JVM:

```
do shell script "export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home'; java -jar /Users/foo/Tn5250j.app/Contents/Resources/Java/tn5250j.jar"
```

(The name of my home directory has been changed "to protect the innocent.")

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall the versions of Java you have and install new ones.

The ones you have are Intel versions and so don't run natively on a Apple Silicon box.

I would note that Java 8 is rather old now and there are many more newer versions. I suspect for ARM you will need one of these. The current long term support from Oracle is Java 17 and the latest normal support is 20.

Install a Java for the arm processor e.g. from from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java20) or [Eclipse](https://adoptium.net/en-GB/temurin/releases/). Other versions come from Azul. All these can be installed from MacPorts in arm and intel versions and they also include versions back to Java 7.

As for Eclipse I think it includes its own Java version by default - so here again try installing an up to date version.

Comment: Hmm. ARM Java doesn't go nearly as far back as 7 and 8.

Comment: I now have ARM-native versions of Zulu 8 and Oracle Java 17 installed. No change in behavior on TN5250j. But installing Oracle Java 17 breaks ***MY*** TN5250 emulator, which I use far more often. So it's gone now.

Comment: I will add that if I drill down to the actual TN5250j.jar within TN5250j.app, and double-click on ***IT,*** it launches just fine.

Comment: That sounds like the way the app was made uses an old way possibly jar-bundler.app if I remeber. You need to remake the app wrapper. This question on SO gives alternatives https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037693/convert-java-application-to-mac-os-x-app javapackager seems to be the current way, other on that page might now be obselete.